# How can I diff two network dumps from tcpdump or Wireshark?

Tags: diff, wireshark, tcpdump

I'm having a problem with one of our customers' embedded computers. They seem to discard some network packets which they should not. I can capture the TCP communication from a managed switch outside the box using Wireshark and I can probably also manage to capture all data from within using tcpdump. I could load both dumps into Wireshark and compare them myself. But is there an easier way to only see the differences between two such dump files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't remember if I've used it or not, but I think [TPCAT](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tpcat/) can do what you're after.

[image: TPCAT screenshot]

Comment: That one doesn't work. Or at least I can't figure out how to use it. It says no single packet would match.

Comment: I think it's based on pcapdiff - does this do the job? https://www.eff.org/testyourisp/pcapdiff/

Comment: I seem to have used it the wrong way. Now I get the message that both captures match. I just need to find a way to drop single packets in the middle of the capture to test it. But it looks good (from a functional perspective, not a stylistic...), thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it's rare to come across a network tool that's both very functional and very beautiful. :) Glad it helped though.

Answer (score 0):

Open both files with vimdiff in hexadecimal mode:

```
$ vimdiff file1.pcap file2.pcap
```

Once in vim, switch each window to hexadecimal mode:

```
:%!xxd
```

[image]